# Using regular expression to extract leaf nodes in phrase structure trees

Tags: regex, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to use regular expression in Java to extract leaf nodes in sentence or phrase structure trees.
For example,
Give a sentence "This is an easy sentence.",

I have syntactic information

Input:
`(ROOT (S (NP (DT This)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT an) (JJ easy) (NN sentence))) (. .)))`

I want to use regular expression to extract leaf nodes

Output:

```
DT This
VBZ is
DT an
JJ easy
NN sentence
.  .
```

Comment: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have nested brackets, then you can use this:

```
(?<=\()[^()]+(?=\))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33so8).

`(?<=\()` is a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that ensures a "(" before the match

`(?=\))` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that ensures a ")" after the match

`[^()]+` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), that matches (one or more) any character, but round brackets.

Comment: It's very useful! Thanks stema!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Stanford NLP based on the tags associated with this question:

A much simpler approach would be to use the inbuilt method [getLeaves()](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html#getLeaves%28%29) in the Tree class.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp you need is `\(([^ ]+) +([^()]+)\)`

It will:
`\(` match an open bracket,
`([^ ]+)` then one or more chars other than a space (and call it group #1),
 `+` then one or more spaces,
`([^()]+)` then one or more chars other than brackets (and call it group #2),
`\)` and finally a closing bracket.

To use it in Java, precompile the pattern in your class:

```
static final Pattern leaf = Pattern.compile("\\(([^ ]+) +([^()]+)\\)");
```

then create a matcher over every input string and loop over its find method:

```
Matcher m = leaf.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    // here do something with each leaf,
    // where m.group(1) is the node type (DT, VBZ...)
    // and m.group(2) is the word
}
```

Comment: Thank Tobia for your enthusiasm. It's very helpful!